# How can I validate that an attribute is not empty if present in a DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

I have an attribute:

```
preprocessFile CDATA #IMPLIED
```

I want this attribute to be:

1. allowed to be absent
2. if present, a non-empty string

How can I express this in a DTD? For the sake of minimizing argument, please assume that I know about rng/xsd and cannot use them for this particular task.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way using an XML DTD to validate that if an attribute is present it must not be empty.

Here are your options:

1. You can set a default value.  For example `preprocessFile CDATA "novalueprovided"`
2. You can allow it to be absent (see your example above).

In either case, you can enforce the attribute to be "absent or not empty if present" in your XML parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with DwB, that this is beyond DTD, which even with the suggestions above would still allow to specify the empty string explicitly. But since DTD also permits no data type specifications, this fits within the picture, since your are not only requiring the string data type but additionally a length restriction. Of course any real schema language like RNG (RelaxNG) or XML:Schema easily supports a check like this, RNG given here:

```
<optional>
    <attribute name="preprocessFile">
       <data type=string">
          <minLength value="1"/>
       </data>
    </attribute>
</optional>
```